# If a set is compact in a smaller metric space, is it compact in a larger metric space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Assume that $(X', d')$ is a metric space such that $X\subseteq X'$ and $d'|_X=d$. (Basically, there is an embedding $(X,d)\hookrightarrow (X',d').$) Let $K\subseteq X$ be compact.

Is it true that $K$ is compact in $X'$ ?

My idea:

In a metric space compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness. Since $K$ is sequentially compact in $(X,d)$, when $K$ is viewed as a subset of $(X,d)$  every sequence in $K$ has a convergent subsequence which converges inside $K$. When $K$ is viewed as a subset of $(X',d')$, the same subsequence will work. Hence $K$ is compact in $(X',d')$.

Comment: Looks good to me. Notice compactness is a property of the topology on $K$. The surrounding space is rather unimportant.

Comment: I agree with @user251257 (especially his or her emphasis on compactness being an intrinsic property):  you have answered your own question.  Incidentally, it's almost as easy to argue directly via the definition of compactness, without any appeal to metric properties.